# file locking mandated by OS/filesystem rather than opted into by file accessors?

Tags: files, filesystems, freebsd, zfs, lock

Is there a way to have the OS (specifically, FreeBSD) or filesystem (specifically, ZFS) enforce that all access (or, at least, all non-root access, I guess) to a certain file must be done while the file is locked? As opposed to something like `lockf`, in which any process that wants to access the file can only access it if it's not *already* locked, and can optionally decide to lock the file?

Something akin to a `chmod` flag, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

No, FreeBSD does not support mandatory locking, neither do most other Unixish systems.

Linux used to have some support for that, but it was ripped out in [v5.14](https://git.kernel.org/linus/f7e33bdbd6d1bdf9c3df8bba5abcf3399f957ac3). (One problem with it being that any process who was allowed to read a file, was also allowed to take a read lock on the file – including system files that need to remain readable.)